# 7 Day Rolling Average

Tags: sql, mysql, moving-average, mysql-5.7, rolling-average

```
insert into 
    job_data(ds,job_id,actor_id,event,language,time_spent,org)
    values
    ('2020-11-30',21,1001,'skip','English',15,'A'),
    ('2020-11-30',22,1006,'transfer','Arabic',25,'B'),
    ('2020-11-29',23,1003,'decision','Persian',20,'C'),
    ('2020-11-28',23,1005,'transfer','Persian',22,'D'),
    ('2020-11-28',25,1002,'decision','Hindi',11,'B'),
    ('2020-11-27',11,1007,'decision','French',104,'D'),
    ('2020-11-26',23,1004,'skip','Persian',56,'A'),
    ('2020-11-25',20,1003,'transfer','Italian',45,'C')
;
```

Above is the table from which I want to find following

Throughput: It is the no. of events happening per second.
And also calculate 7 day rolling average of throughput.

I'm using MySQL version 5 and  the following is my query. but I can't getting the out put.

```
CREATE VIEW t AS(
SELECT ds,
    COUNT(\*)/SUM(time_spent) AS t1
FROM job_data
Group By ds);

SELECT 
    ds AS 'Date',
    COUNT(\*) / SUM(time_spent) AS 'Throughput',
    (SELECT t1
    FROM t as x
    HAVING x.ds \>= t.ds - INTERVAL 6 DAY
        AND   x.ds \<= t.ds
    ) AS '7'
FROM
    job_data
GROUP BY ds
ORDER BY ds;
```

Comment: Narrow this post to one problem only. If you want to address throughput, only add data for throughput and expected output. If you want to address the rolling average, only add data for rolling average and expected output.

Comment: Change `having` to `where` and it works: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F4XcA0Pi).